# c# продолжить выполнение после выбора элемента в combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Не пойму как сделать.
По кнопке открываю диалоговое окно и загружаю xml.
Сombobox заполняется данными.
Далее хочу выбрать значение в CB и продолжить выполнение программы.
Как вариант сделать 2 кнопки и последовательно их нажимать, но это как-то не очень.

Как можно сделать например?

```
if (выбран элемент combobox)
{
}
```

или другой вариант

Comment: Если хотите продолжить выполнение сразу, как пользователь выберет (то есть тыкнет на элемент СВ), тл вешайте обработчик на соответствующий Event комбобокса. Хотя такой вариант не очень хорош - все иногда мышкой тыкают не туда, лучше кнопку подтверждения.

Comment: Обычно подобное реализуется при помощи async/await. Почитайте, например, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что означает продолжение программы. В одном потоке, нескольких?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через механизм делегатов.

```
public static class IOData {
   public delegate void Run();
   public static Run EventHandlerRun;
}

public void Load(){
    ....
    IOData.EventHandlerRun = new IOData.Run(func);
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   IOData.Run();
}

private void func(){

}
```

или просто

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    func();
}
```

Comment: Да. второй код. Всего лишь 2 раза нажать на комбобокс

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить Event как посоветовали, а можно примитивным способом через switch